# React-typescript: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: authentication, input, onchange, react-typescript

I am using React-typescript for my. I have one login page where there are two input fields. one is email and password. i have created one state and inside the state there `email` `password` and `loading`. Default input fields works fine, I have target my input fields with `id`. I have decided, I will create global input fields and custom props. When I used global input fields then it does not target the `id`  and throws me this error: `React-typescript: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. I am pretty sure in my typescript `onChange` throws me that error. But Don't know to how to fix it. Here is my code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-mcclintock-tjxj8?file=/src/App.tsx).

**This is my Login form**

```
import React, { ReactElement, useState } from "react";

import { TextInput } from "./input";

interface Props extends PageProps {}

export default function SignIn({}: Props): ReactElement {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: ``,
    password: ``,
    loading: false
  });
  const { loading, email, password } = state;
  const handleSignIn = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value //This is id which throws me error
    });
  };
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
    setState({
      loading: true,
      ...state
    });
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://run.mocky.io/v3/beec46b8-8536-4cb1-9304-48e96d341461",
      {
        method: `POST`,
        headers: {
          Accept: `application/json`,
          "Content-Type": `application/json`
        },
        body: { state }
      }
    );
    console.log(response);

    if (response.ok) {
      setState({ ...state, loading: false });
      alert(`login succs`);
    } else {
      alert(`login failed`);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={handleSignIn}
        id="email"
        required
      />
      <TextInput
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={handleSignIn}
        id="password"
        required
      />
      <button type="submit" name="action" onClick={onSubmit} disabled={loading}>
        {" "}
        {loading ? `loading...` : `save`}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**this is my global input**

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface Props {
  value: string;
  onChange: (e: string) => void;
  error?: string;
  id?: string;
}

const Input = styled.input``;

// eslint-disable-next-line func-style
export function TextInput({ value, onChange, error, id }: Props): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div>
      <Input
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
        error={error}
        id={id}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I found my solution: I have created two handle changes functions, one for email and on for password..
``
const handleEmail = (email: string) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      email
    });
  };
  const handlePassword = (password: string) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      password
    });
  };

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution: I have created two handle changes functions, one for email and one for password..

```
`const handleEmail = (email: string) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      email
    });
  };
  const handlePassword = (password: string) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      password
    });
  };`
```